# How to use AWK Using with IF Condition

Tags: unix, if-statement, awk, delimiter, fs

I need to use AWK command to find count of delimiters in a file and if the count is more than expected then I need to captuure the records.

Code used:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS= "^A"; if ( 31 < NF-1) print $0 }'  file.dat
```

but it is not working.

Comment: This is because you are working within the `BEGIN` block

Comment: Is your `^A` delimiter an actual sequence or a string?

Comment: Post sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As fedorqui comments, you don't have any data in a BEGIN block. You have to read at least 1 record to determine how many fields you have:

```
awk -F"^A" 'NR==1 && NF >= 32 {exit} {print}'  file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter version:

```
awk -F"^A" 'NF > 32'  file.dat
```

Your original construct was `31 < NF-1` which is just a more complex way of saying `NF>32`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `"^A"` is a string of two characters

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS= "\\^A"} NF-1 > 32'  file.dat
```

will do, as `{print}` is the default action for a match and the two most
common instances of awk (gawk and mawk) both translate `"\\^A"` to a literal
caret followed by the letter `A`.

On the other hand if `"^A"` means `Control-A` you must properly
quote the control character when you type the line at the shell prompt
(e.g., in bash+readline it is `Control-V` `Control-A`) and you must not
use the backslashes.